react native auth provider effect not triggering for is authenticated check using firebase
I'm creating a register screen for my app, and to do that, I created a OnAuth hook, to register the login/register and logout functionality, and also manage the is authenticated state as wel as the user.
interface authProperties {
  user: {user: any};
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  register: (
    email: string,
    password: string,
    firstname: string,
    lastname: string,
  ) => Promise<any>;
  login: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<any>;
  logout: () => Promise<any>;
}

export const authContext = createContext<authProperties>({} as authProperties);

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<{user: any}>({user: null});
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
      console.log('AuthProvider effect triggered', user);
      if (user) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        setUser({user});
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        setUser({user: null});
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    // login logic
  };
  const register = async (
    email: string,
    password: string,
    firstname: string,
    lastname: string,
  ) => {
    // register logic
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    // logout logic
  }; 

  const value = {
    user,
    isAuthenticated,
    register,
    login,
    logout,
  };

  return <authContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</authContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  const value = useContext(authContext);

  if (!value) {
    throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider');
  }

  return value;
};

then in my App.tsx I'm setting a useEffect to trigger when isAuthenticated is changed.
const App = () => {
  // new auth state
  const {isAuthenticated} = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('App useEffect triggered');
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      console.log('User is authenticated');
    } else {
      console.log('User is not authenticated');
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      {isAuthenticated ? (
        <TabNavigator />
      ) : (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Routes />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      )}
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;


When I register a new user, the effect inside my authprovider is triggered correctly. I get logs, when entering, and when registering, I get the correct firebase user, token, etcetera.
however, I expected that the useEffect on isAuthenticated would be triggered too. Since here I want to have the logic to go to either a tabnavigator(when authenticated), or to the signing/signup (when not authenticated)
I'm relatively new to react native, and not sure why this effect is not triggered.
If anyone knows, it would be much appreciated!

The App component is accessing the context of some AuthProvider component rendered above it in the ReactTree, not the one it renders itself. Since you are complaining or asking why an 'useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider' isn't thrown I make the assumption that there is more than one AuthProvider being rendered and that there is actually one above App.
You likely need only one AuthProvider component per app, so the entire app accesses the same single provided context value. You can remove the extraneous AuthProvider component that App renders.
<AuthProvider>
  <App />
</AuthProvider>

Preferred method using useContext hook.
const App = () => {
  // new auth state
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('App useEffect triggered');
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      console.log('User is authenticated');
    } else {
      console.log('User is not authenticated');
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <TabNavigator />
    : (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Routes />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
};

export default App;

On the off-hand chance that the AuthProvider component App renders is the only one and there actually is some error, then either move AuthProvider higher in the ReactTree than App so App can access it.
Alternative using Context Consumer
You could also use a Context Consumer to conditionally render the navigator or routes. This still assumes an AuthProvider component is rendered higher in the ReactTree and App.
Example:
const App = () => {
  return (
    <authContext.Consumer>
      {({ isAuthenticated }) => {
        return isAuthenticated
          ? <TabNavigator />
          : (
            <SafeAreaProvider>
              <NavigationContainer>
                <Routes />
              </NavigationContainer>
            </SafeAreaProvider>
          );
      }}
    </authContext.Consumer>
  );
};

